# Short syntax for NSString Multilanguage allocation

Tags: java, objective-c, macros

I've a method called S that convert an NSString* through a KeyValue approach to another NSString* in another language

```
static inline NSString* S(NSString *stringa);
```

For a trivial migration to Java code I've defined this preprocessor macro:

```
   #define String NSString*
   #define SS(stringa) S(@#stringa)
```

So in my objc code I can do something like this:

```
String translated = SS(string_to_translate);
```

but string_to_translate  is a NSString* so I can't use brace tu include the real string. My intention, for an easy migration to Java syntax was to have a macro in objc that can do this:

```
String translated = SS("string_to_translate");
```

without using objc "@" but only brace parentheses.

Comment: The `S(@#stringa)` macro will convert `S(hello)` into `@"hello"` so if you want to use `S("hello")` instead then remove the stringify  operator (`#`).

Comment: @trojanfoe than it works